# Is it possible to replace string with * in xsl 1.0

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I am using following template to print some data

```
<xsl:template name="AgeGroupTotalHiddenHeader">
    <tr style='visibility:collapse'>
        <xsl:for-each select="child::SubDetailBody/SubDetailHeader">
            <xsl:if test="name(.) = 'SubDetailHeader' and @beanType='AGE_DATA'">
                <xsl:for-each select="Label">
                    <td align="center" class="txtsmall3">
                        <xsl:value-of select="@textLabel" />
                    </td>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </tr>
</xsl:template>
```

I want value of @textLabel to be replaced with * sign, that is if the string is 'abcde' it should be printed as ***** (length of 'abcde' = 5 so there should be 5 stars). Is this possible ? can anyone please help?

Comment: Please post a [mcve].

Comment: Thank you @michael.hor257k. What are the extra details that I can provide to you

Comment: Input XML. A complete, executable stylesheet. Expected output. Which processor you will be using. And, no less importantly, remove the code that's not relevant to the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know the maximum possible length of the input string, you could use:

```
<xsl:value-of select="substring('*********************', 1, string-length($input))"/>
```

If you know in advance all possible characters that the input string can contain, you could do something like:

```
<xsl:value-of select="translate($input, 'abcdefgh', '********')"/>
```

(make sure the number of characters in the 2nd and 3rd parameter is the same).

If neither assumption is true, then it gets more complicated.

---

Side note: if this is related to security, you should be aware that knowing the length of an obscured string may be valuable to the attacker.

Comment: that worked, is it possible to replace with space instead of *, I tried with the first approach but its not working, is there any way?

Comment: It works for me: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/nbiE1av

Comment: But was not working in my case, and I used _ which is also acceptable in my case, Thank you so much @michael.hor257k for your help which saved a lot of my time.

Comment: Perhaps you are viewing the result in a browser - which will reduce runs of whitespace characters to a single space.